# AngularJS and Asp.Net WebApi not showing data in firefox / chrome

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have an Asp.Net WebApi server running on port 8080 that exposes a GET method (let's say `IEnumerable<Friend> Get()`).

I have another Asp.Net site running on port 55163 that contains an AnugularJs project.

When I'm calling `$resource('...localhost:8080/api/friends')` from the angular controller and present data like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="friend in friends">
        {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old.
    </li>
</ul>
```

the page is not showing any list in Firefox and Chrome. I've noticed that with IE no problems so far.

I've been checking the XHR request call from Firefox and the JSON is returned back properly to the client.

I'm using AngularJs 1.2.16 and AspNet.WebApi 5.1.2

**MORE DETAILS**

in my controller if I'm doing this (not calling the service):

```
$scope.friends = [
    { name: 'Person1', age: 30 },
    { name: 'Person2', age: 30 }
];
```

the scope is correctly set, but if I'm doing that:

```
$http.get('...localhost:8080/api/friends').success(function (data) {
    $scope.friends = [];
    angular.forEach(data, function (item) {
        $scope.friends.push(item);
    });
});
```

or that:

```
var userResource = $resource('...localhost:8080/api/friends');
userResource.query({ method: 'GET', isArray: true }, function (data) {
    $scope.friends = [];
    angular.forEach(data, function (item) {
        $scope.friends.push(item);
    });
});
```

the scope is not populated ... (or it is just for Internet Explorer)

**UPDATE 1**

If I put everything under the same server then works, I wonder if it is related to CORS somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The first place to check for AngularJS issues is the browser console. Any errors are usually logged there.

If there are no errors, `friends` is likely not being populated correctly. Have you tried debugging the result of the XHR and confirming whether the result is being assigned to friends?

Comment: See MORE DETAILS above. Thanks!

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in the query() method on IE, is it hit? In other words, is the forEach loop running?

Comment: Yes in IE using vs2013 debugger the breakpoint is reached and the javascript array is correctly populated

Comment: Nope, that is really a strange behavior!

Comment: similar issue . . . My call to a WebApiController method returns all the records and I can see all records  on the cshtml page when running locally in VS2013 debug mode but when published to IIS server, no data is displayed.  My libraries are referenced locally and it is not a CSS issue.   In Chrome, all the libraries are there when running.  Console has no scripting errors.  The data is not binding to repeater from IIS server. WTF!?!?